# iOS UISearchBar height in landscape mode in navigationBar iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, height, uisearchbar, landscape

I need help with searchBar in landscape mode. I am adding it to the navigationBar titleView - centered:

```
self.searchBarTop = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBarTop;
```

In landscape mode it is to big to fit in properly:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this is gray area customizing UISearchBar. I have managed to use another way moving searchBar outside the navigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to find the Orientation of the iphone and then set accordingly frame of SearchBar.Set the frame of the SearchBar (Portrait mode) in ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 310.0, 44.0)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {     

        UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
        UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 310.0, 44.0)];
        searchBar.delegate = self;
        [searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;
    }
    else
    {
        UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5.0, 0.0, 480.0, 44.0)];
        UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 470.0, 44.0)];
         searchBar.delegate = self;
        [searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;

    }
}
```

It will surely help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. You always set height to 44 points. But navigationController in landscape mode has height 32 points. Like so I need height of the searchBar 30 points or less (1 point top/bottom margin).

Comment: change the height of the searchBar which ever you want in if else section of this code line         UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 470.0, 44.0)];

Comment: Nope, this doesn't help either. Obviously the height of the searchBar could not be changed...